# Wordpress, Huge category CSV import does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, import, categories

I have a 1.5 MB (with about 20.000 line) CSV file and I would like to import this into my new WordPress site. The code below does not create all of the categories, only some of them. I already increased the following settings for PHP:

```
max_execution_time = 2000
max_input_time = 2000
max_input_vars = 20000
memory_limit = 1024M
```

I've tried split the CSV into multiple separate files, but it will take longer to code execution. The first piece execute in 30 seconds but the second about 10 minutes and does not create all of the categories.

Can someone help me with what's wrong?

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '2000');
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wpse_57865_activation_run');

function wpse_57865_activation_run()
{
    $file = file_get_contents( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . 'categories.csv' );
    $data = array_map( "str_getcsv", preg_split( '/\r*\n+|\r+/', $file ) );

    if( count($data) < 1)
        return;

    foreach( $data as $cat )
    {
        $cat_defaults = array(
          'cat_name' => $cat[0],
          'category_nicename' => $cat[1] 
        );

        wp_insert_category($cat_defaults);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to take a look at this one https://github.com/A5hleyRich/wp-background-processing

Comment: Why not break it into smaller files?